# Automated tests too slow on Jenkins

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, xvfb

I'm running Selenium Webdrive tests on Jenkins (Debian 9 without GUI) using Chromedriver and xvfb, and they are extremely slow as compared to local execution. A click is done in 4 minutes comparing to 300 ~ 400 milliseconds on my local machine.

the details of the environment are as follows :

- **Jenkins** (running on Debian 9 without GUI) + Xvfb
- **Chrome** = 67.0.3396.99
- **Java.version**: '1.8.0_171'
- **Chromedriver Version**: 2.40.565383
- **Selenium-java** = 3.13.0

(The test project is in java (maven) with the framework TestNg v6.14.3)

I tried also **Firefox**, it's not as long as Chrome but it's still long compared to local

Any ideas ?

Comment: What machine running these tests? Master or slave? Physical/docker/vm ?

Comment: Without gui means headless chrome?

Comment: @AutomatedOwl, on the master and it's a VM

Comment: @AutomatedOwl Yes but i'm using the Xvfb not the --headless argument of Chrome, i tried the --headless but it does not seem to change anything

Comment: Try to increase your vm resources or running on headless chrome

Comment: @AutomatedOwl, the same thing, always slow with the headless mode

Comment: Have you checked here https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/robotframework-users/ouO-FgGhWKk ?

Comment: I also have same issue. Headless Chrome (Xvfb) on Jenkins(Centos7) or Chrome on my laptop doesn't make any difference. Master or Slave doesnt make any difference. Looking forward for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try these two ChromeOptions:

```
options.addArguments("--proxy-server='direct://'");
options.addArguments("--proxy-bypass-list=*");
```

I found it [here](https://github.com/Codeception/CodeceptJS/issues/561) :